# What am I missing to get the "Unsung Hero" badge?

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I know this is asked quite often but I checked everything and I still don't get why it's not awarded.

When I run [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) I get that I have the following stats:

```
Accepted Answers Scored Answers Unscored Answers Percentage Unscored 
---------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------- 
25               15             10               40
```

To most of the "not awarded cases" the answers are either "not old enough" (10 days old) or "some of the answers are self answered". Neither is the case here.

Please help me out.

Comment: Here is a working query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The badge description says (emphasis mine):

> Zero score accepted answers: **more than** 10 and 25% of total

So you need 11 zero-score accepted answers and not 10.